# Why does Istio require Pods belong to at least one Service in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Istio's deployment requirements state that a [Pod must belong to at least one Kubernetes Service](https://istio.io/docs/ops/deployment/requirements/) in order to form part of an Istio mesh. One of the reasons for this as I understand it is to create an entry to refer to the Pod (or group of Pods) in configuration rules (e.g. `<serviceName>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`).

Are there any other reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Many of Istio's features (policy enforcement, distributed tracing, cross-service metrics) depend on knowing what service a request is coming *from*.  Ordinarily you only need to create Kubernetes services to route inbound requests to specific pods, but Istio uses them more generally to associate pods with abstract "services".

Say pod A is calling pod B.  Even in plain Kubernetes you need a service for B, and the request from A would target the service rather than the pod directly.  If you set up, for example, [metrics](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/observability/#metrics) in Istio (maybe using its built-in Prometheus), then Istio also tries to look up a service for A.  If it finds it then you'll see metrics like `istio_requests_total(source_service="A", destination_service="B")`.  If it doesn't the source will just show up as "unknown".

Comment: So are you saying Istio only uses Services for naming services? (this is what I was referring to when I said it's used to create an entry to refer to groups of Pods) And the normal use case in Kubernetes (i.e. routing requests to Pods) isn't used?

Comment: Both use cases are important.

Comment: Well, the concept of "service" has changed over time and now they more refer to "workloads" for something that emits a request, service being now closer to what it is in kubernetes. In metrics, `source_service` doesn't exist anymore, it's `source_workload` and refers to a deployment/replicaset, not a service. However, Istio still needs to assume there are services in front of pods, else some functionalities wouldn't work (e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/istio-users/8MEXiwGfhqw or https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7787 )

Comment: The concept of a Service (capital S) in Kubernetes hasn't changed though which is what I was trying to ask about - I wanted to clarify what "important" meant, how does Istio use them that makes them important?